# Comment image in caption

Tags: graphics, captions

I want comment an image inside `caption{}`, but I don't want have the comment in the table of image. So I used `caption*{}`.

```
\begin{figure}[H] \centering
    \includegraphics[height=6cm, width=0.65\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{figure/campione}
    \caption{\textit{text}}\caption*{\textit{comment}}
\end{figure}
```

I'd like to have the comment right after `text`; as `comment` is the continue of `text` because with this code `comment` goes in a new line.
[image: How it is]

[image: How I want]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this? `\caption` has an optional argument, which you can use to have a different text in the List of Figures.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}[hbt]
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption[Short caption for LoF]{Really long caption with lots of info}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You're right. I forgot of `[]`. Thanks